# vlc: convert multiple files

Tags: vlc, mp4

I want to convert multiple files  from .mov to .mp4. I have used `vlc` for converting single files. Can I batch convert using `vlc`? I know it is possible on `windows`, and I have found many tutorials.

Comment: I find Handbrake easier for dealing with multiple files - used to send it 40 files…

Answer (score 2):

[HandBrake](https://handbrake.fr/) is the tool of choice to batch-convert video files.

If you want to use VLC, check out the script at https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HowTo/Transcode_multiple_videos/.

Comment: I  would prefer to rewrite it in python. Shall the command be the following:  `vlc -I dummy -q <filename>  --sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,vb=1024,acodec=mp4a,ab=128}:standard{mux=mp4,dst=<filename>.transcoded,access=file}`

Comment: I had already compressed a video manually with vlc and got a compression of ~5. Which parameters do set, and how can I check them in order to achieve this compression? That is default in vlc